# using AsyncTask to download image (url)

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I've made a piece of a code that suppose to download image from the internet using url and display it in `ImageView` the problem is that I am getting a null pointer exception and I cannot locate the problem

Here is the piece of the code in the activity

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.btnShow:
        DownloadImageTask download=new DownloadImageTask(this);
        String imageUrl = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.editUrl)).getText().toString(); 
        download.execute(imageUrl); 

        break;

    }
}
```

and here is the AsyncTask Code

```
public class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Bitmap> {
    private Activity mActivity;  
    private ProgressDialog mDialog;


    public DownloadImageTask(Activity mActivity) {
        super();
        this.mActivity = mActivity;
    }

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) mActivity.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(null);
        mDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        mDialog.setCancelable(true);
        mDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        mDialog.setProgress(0);       
    }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        Log.d("doInBackground", "starting download of image");        
        Bitmap image = downloadImage(urls[0]);
        return image;
    } 
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {   
        mDialog.show();
        mDialog.setProgress(progress[0]);        
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        if (result != null) {            
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) mActivity.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(result);
        }
        else {

        }

        mDialog.dismiss();
    }

    private Bitmap downloadImage(String urlString) {
        URL url;        
        try {
            url = new URL(urlString);
            HttpURLConnection httpCon = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();          

            InputStream is = httpCon.getInputStream();          
            int fileLength = httpCon.getContentLength();
            mDialog.setMax(fileLength);
            ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            int nRead, totalBytesRead = 0;          
            byte[] data = new byte[2048];

            while ((nRead = is.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1) {
                buffer.write(data, 0, nRead);
                totalBytesRead += nRead;                
                publishProgress(totalBytesRead);               
            }          

            byte[] image = buffer.toByteArray();             
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image, 0, image.length);             
            return bitmap;
        } catch (Exception e) {            
            e.printStackTrace();
        }     
        return null;
    }
}
```

That is the logCat errors

```
12-17 16:15:33.938: E/AndroidRuntime(29324): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-17 16:15:33.938: E/AndroidRuntime(29324): Process: com.example.movieandroidproject, PID: 29324
12-17 16:15:33.938: E/AndroidRuntime(29324): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-17 16:15:33.938: E/AndroidRuntime(29324):    at com.example.asyncTask.DownloadImageTask.onPreExecute(DownloadImageTask.java:30)
12-17 16:15:33.938: E/AndroidRuntime(29324):    at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:587)
12-17 16:15:33.938: E/AndroidRuntime(29324):    at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:535)
12-17 16:15:33.938: E/AndroidRuntime(29324):    at com.example.movieandroidproject.ChooseMovieAdd.onClick(ChooseMovieAdd.java:89)
12-17 16:15:33.938: E/AndroidRuntime(29324):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4461)
12-17 16:15:33.938: E/AndroidRuntime(29324):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18525)
12-17 16:15:33.938: E/AndroidRuntime(29324):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
12-17 16:15:33.938: E/AndroidRuntime(29324):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
12-17 16:15:33.938: E/AndroidRuntime(29324):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
12-17 16:15:33.938: E/AndroidRuntime(29324):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5118)
12-17 16:15:33.938: E/AndroidRuntime(29324):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-17 16:15:33.938: E/AndroidRuntime(29324):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-17 16:15:33.938: E/AndroidRuntime(29324):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:794)
12-17 16:15:33.938: E/AndroidRuntime(29324):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:610)
12-17 16:15:33.938: E/AndroidRuntime(29324):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should close your input streams.

```
buffer.close();
is.close();
```

sencodly you should check if there is any exceptions that is thrown and catched here because you are returning null at the end of the function.

```
try {
        url = new URL(urlString);
        HttpURLConnection httpCon = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();          

        InputStream is = httpCon.getInputStream();          
        int fileLength = httpCon.getContentLength();
        mDialog.setMax(fileLength);
        ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        int nRead, totalBytesRead = 0;          
        byte[] data = new byte[2048];

        while ((nRead = is.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1) {
            buffer.write(data, 0, nRead);
            totalBytesRead += nRead;                
            publishProgress(totalBytesRead);               
        }          

        byte[] image = buffer.toByteArray();             
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image, 0, image.length);             
        return bitmap;
    } catch (Exception e) { 
        // here           
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

your mDialog field is not initialized when you call

```
    mDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public DownloadImageTask(Activity mActivity) {
    super();
    this.mActivity = mActivity;
    this.mDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
}
```

But this is bad solution. As for me, better would be create showProgress and hideProgress methods in the activity, and call them in onPreExecute and in onPostExecute in your task.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is not in AsyncTask, instead problem is in Progress Bar. You have not initialized it :

```
mProgress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);   // This line is missing...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify the method you are using to download the image like this

```
public Bitmap downloadImage(String src){
        try {
            URL url = new URL(src);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
            return  myBitmap;
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Then you use it like:

```
protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        Log.d("doInBackground", "starting download of image");        
        Bitmap image = downloadImage(urls[0]);
        return image;
    } 
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {   
        mDialog.show();
        mDialog.setProgress(progress[0]);        
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        if (result != null) {            
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) mActivity.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(result);
        }
        else {

        }

        mDialog.dismiss();
    }
```